# Using Git SHA commit ID as artifact version number when publishing to Artifactory in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

We have a Gradle project in a Git repository that Jenkins monitors for commits.  When a new commit comes in it kicks off the build pipeline.  At the end of the pipeline it publishes the jar file to Artifactory.

I want Jenkins to use the Git SHA commit ID has the artifact version number of the published jar.  I see that the Jenkins Git plugin saves the commit ID in an environment variable called GIT_COMMIT.  But how do I tell the Jenkins Artifactory plugin to use this value for the version number?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to abuse the file name with additional metadata, since Artifactory knows how to store the metadata for the files.

More so, all the files built by Jenkins with Jenkins Artifactory plugin, or with Gradle with Gradle Artifactory plugin already have this information.

Here's an example of the properties passed by Jenkins to Arifactory. As you can see, the `vcs.revision` includes the information you need:
[image]

Comment: But I don't want to maintain a different version number (3.5 in your example) and I want every build artifact to be saved and accessible.  I don't want to replace the current artifact with the new one, I want the new one to be it's own artifact.

Comment: For that Artifactory supports unique snapshots. Just deploy artifacts with let's say `1.0-SNAPSHOT`, and it will automatically generate unique version for every deployed artifacts. You then will be able to retrieve the latest by using `-SNAPSHOT`, or search by properties (`vcs.revision`) to cherry-pick a specific one.